# C# Code optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

who could be faster ? and why ?

1:

```
Point point = new Point(25,25);   //any numbers..
Point point2 = new Point(20,95);  //any numbers..

Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
g.DrawLine(point,point2);
```

OR

2:

```
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
g.DrawLine(new Point(25,25),new Point(20,95));
```

Comment: sugest you benchmark using System.Diagnostics.StopWatch. Question has little or no value to a wider audience...

Comment: I think the question is valid, don't see why the downvotes !!

Comment: The question is valid, but pointless. It's micro-optimization at best, preference at worst.

Comment: I think the question is valid in its generalised form. I find arul's answer interesting.

Comment: @Eric, who's to say it's pointless for the OP?

Comment: Profiling + ILDASM my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither, there is no real difference between them except for the loss in readability (especially after a JITing).

Comment: what about memory? i thought that the first one create in memory two points (objects) but the second one doesn't create in memory?
is that right ????

Comment: @mavric - are created the same way -- on the stack (at least I think Point is a structure).  The only difference even with reference types is that in #1, in debug mode, the Point objects won't be collected until you exit the method.  In release mode, the objects will have the same lifetime.

Answer (score 15):

None of them, since both snippets will compile to the same MSIL code representation.

Besides, this is a micro-optimization, which you should avoid before actually knowing that it **is the bottleneck.**

Answer (score 2):

Micro Optimization, huh? One notable playwright says [code readability is more important than micro optimizations](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001218.html), and I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is faster, the fastest one would be the one that avoids allocating those points in the Render path altogether and precreates them earlier

Answer (score 0):

2 might be faster because you're not creating intermediate pointers to the object before passing it to g.DrawLine; however, if that's the only place you use point and point2 then the compiler will likely optimize so the binary is the same anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what else you're doing.

If you're doing almost nothing else (which I doubt) then this is the "bottleneck".

If this is the "bottleneck" then you still don't know what's dominant:

- two "new"s and associated constructors, destructors, and garbage collection.
- actually rendering lines.

The second is probably unavoidable, but the first is only there for style reasons.

You can find out by profiling or [this simple method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Or you can avoid the whole question with:

```
g.DrawLine(25,25,20,95);
```